# FILE_NOT_FOUND when trying to open COM port C++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am trying to open a com port for reading and writing using C++ but I can't seem to pass the first stage of actually opening it. I get an `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on the handle
with `GetLastError FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I have searched around the web  for a couple of days I'm fresh out of ideas. I have searched through all the questions regarding COM on this website too.

I have scanned through the existing ports (or so I believe) to get the name of the port right.

I also tried combinations of `_T("COM1")` with the slashes, without the slashes, with colon, without colon and without the _T

I'm using windows 7 on 64 bit machine.

this is the code i got

I'll be glad for any input on this

```
void SendToCom(char* data, int len)
{

DWORD cbNeeded = 0;
DWORD dwPorts = 0;
EnumPorts(NULL, 1, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &dwPorts);

//What will be the return value
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

LPCSTR COM1 ;

BYTE* pPorts = static_cast<BYTE*>(malloc(cbNeeded));
bSuccess = EnumPorts(NULL, 1, pPorts, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded, &dwPorts);
if (bSuccess){
    PORT_INFO_1* pPortInfo = reinterpret_cast<PORT_INFO_1*>(pPorts);
    for (DWORD i=0; i<dwPorts; i++)
    {
        //If it looks like "COMX" then          
        size_t nLen = _tcslen(pPortInfo->pName);
        if (nLen > 3)
        {
            if ((_tcsnicmp(pPortInfo->pName, _T("COM"), 3) == 0) ){
                COM1 =pPortInfo->pName;
                //COM1 ="\\\\.\\COM1";
                HANDLE m_hCommPort = CreateFile( COM1 ,
                    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,  // access ( read and write)
                    0,                           // (share) 0:cannot share the COM port
                    NULL,                           // security  (None)
                    OPEN_EXISTING,               // creation : open_existing
                    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,        // we want overlapped operation
                    NULL                            // no templates file for COM port...
                    );
                if (m_hCommPort==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    DWORD err = GetLastError();
                    if (err == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
                        MessageBox(hWnd,"ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND",NULL,MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
                    }
                    else
                        if(err == ERROR_INVALID_NAME) {
                            MessageBox(hWnd,"ERROR_INVALID_NAME",NULL,MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox(hWnd,"unkown error",NULL,MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
                        }
                }
                else{
                    WriteAndReadPort(m_hCommPort,data);
                }
            }
            pPortInfo++;
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: `_T` has been redundant for 10 years now. Windows 95 is dead.

Comment: Pretty rare to run into COM1 these days, they are reserved for legacy hardware.  Don't use EnumPorts(), that's for printers.  Use the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM registry key.

Comment: If `CreateFile()` fails with error 2 for both `\\.\COM1` and `COM1`, then you really do not have a COM1 port installed. Go into `Control Panel > Device Manager > Ports` to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.
1. I don't have SERIALCOMM
2. I don't have ports entry under device manager

Comment: @RemyLebeau This doesn't appear to be the case. I get that error but the port is definitely listed in the device manager. No idea why.

Comment: @Timmmm: and you are sure the port actually maps to COM1 and simply does not mention COM1 in its display name?

Answer (score 4):

The Solution is to use

The Problem is, if your port is Bigger then 9 then you have to use the Syntax 
`LPCWSTR szPortName =  L"\\\\.\\COM11";`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9-db9078a5-b7b6-bf00-240f-f749ebfd913e

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10 - running all system updates might help !

I had the same issue that opening port "COM4" returned an error ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. When running the program as "Administrator" it worked. Now after a updating to 1511 the program can open "COM4" even not running as "Administrator".

Comment: Well, it can't be windows 10 since this question was asked long before windows 10 came to be :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/163855/
Use CreateFileA(...) instead of CreateFile(...)

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` can be produced from `CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM1", ...)` and `CreateFile(L"COM1:", ...)` after using the Device Manager to change the assigned COM Port number.  Disabling and re-enabling the device, or unplugging and reconnecting the USB adapter resolves the issue.

A useful test to confirm whether it is your program or the system is to send data to the port in command prompt.  A successful test will show an empty line.  A failed test will show an error message.

```
C:\drop>echo > \\.\COM1
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\drop>echo > \\.\COM1

C:\drop>
```